# Android: Call fragment functions from Activity, the fragment function contains getActivity() and returns null

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment as follows:

```
public class F1 extends Fragment {

    ...
    public void function1 (){
        activity = getActivity();
    }

}
```

When trying to call this function in the activity which has this fragment,

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    private F1 f1 = new F1();
    f1.function1();

}
```

it returns `null`.

How can I solve this problem? Can anyone provide a working code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null because the fragment didn't attach to the Activity. so use Fragment Manager to access Fragments and also you can use Activity Context in onAttach(Activity activity) , and it would be for sure not Null.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activityContext = activity; //then use activity context
}
```

and for getting your Fragment Instance :

```
F1 f1 = (F1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(F1.TAG_FRAGMENT);
```